# WSO2 ESB XSLT mediator with CDATA

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to translate XML as CDATA, use XSLT mediator,

in client, send below message as application/xml,

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>user-1</name>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <job>DBA</job>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>user-2</name>
    <sex>F</sex>
    <job>BPMS</job>
  </user>
</users>
```

in proxy service,

```
<inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <xslt key="test_xslt"/>
   <log level="full">
      <property name="text" value="===================="/>
   </log>
</inSequence>
```

and XSLT of local entry "test_xslt",

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <body xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <op_test_xml_parm>
          <clob_xml>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
          </clob_xml>
        </op_test_xml_parm>
      </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output:

```
[2013-07-03 18:30:42,998]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/test_xslt, MessageID: urn:uuid:7dff989b-7dc1-41b4-8826-55685009d4b5, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><body xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <op_test_xml_parm>
      <clob_xml>&lt;users xmlns="">
            &lt;user>
               &lt;name>user-1&lt;/name>
               &lt;sex>M&lt;/sex>
               &lt;job>DBA&lt;/job>
            &lt;/user>
            &lt;user>
               &lt;name>user-2&lt;/name>
               &lt;sex>F&lt;/sex>
               &lt;job>BPMS&lt;/job>
            &lt;/user>
         &lt;/users></clob_xml>
   </op_test_xml_parm>
</body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2013-07-03 18:30:43,005]  INFO - LogMediator text = ====================
```

The result I expect is:

```
<body xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <op_test_xml_parm>
      <clob_xml><![CDATA[<users xmlns="">
            <user>
               <name>user-1</name>
               <sex>M</sex>
               <job>DBA</job>
            </user>
            <user>
               <name>user-2</name>
               <sex>F</sex>
               <job>BPMS</job>
            </user>
         </users>]]></clob_xml>
   </op_test_xml_parm>
</body>
```

if any one can help me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an issue. The one you expect (i.e. with CDATA tag) and the one you get (i.e. with "& lt;"s) are the same, semantically.

You can proceed without worrying about that.

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, thanks your reply.  <br/>
I want to pass the CDATA (<users> ... ... </users>) as parameter to WSO2 DSS and call stored procedure.  <br/>

But the result could not finish the proccess of WSO2 DSS.

Comment: I copy the
`&lt;users xmlns="">
    &lt;user>
       &lt;name>user-1&lt;/name>
       &lt;sex>M&lt;/sex>
       &lt;job>DBA&lt;/job>
    &lt;/user>
    &lt;user>
       &lt;name>user-2&lt;/name>
       &lt;sex>F&lt;/sex>
       &lt;job>BPMS&lt;/job>
    &lt;/user>
 &lt;/users>`
    to WSO2 DSS 「Try it」 page, **it is working** .

    But it is **not work in WSO2 DSS**.
    I have no idea.

Comment: I will transform message (XML) via WSO2 ESB XSLT mediator, and then send the payload to WSO2 DSS, WSO2 DSS use the CDATA as a parameter to call DB stored procedure (Oracle).

Comment: No error, but no response too. I was send payload from ESB proxy service **in-sequence**, and in the **out-sequence**:
`LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:e7014344-ba2a-42d5-9e9b-992713f0e046, Direction: response, text = ========== Begin out-sequence ==========, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: It's work by drop <body> </body> tag.
Thanks Rata and Bhathiya.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in your xslt script..there are number of resources on how to insert cdata using xslt..you can check them..

Comment: Hi Ratha, 
thanks your suggestion.

But before I add XSLT mediator to WSO2 ESB, I was test it in
[link](http://xslttest.appspot.com/)

the result is as my expected.